# How can I sync /var/www folder with Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

How can I sync `/var/www` folder with Ubuntu One?

I tried symlink with `ln -s /var/www www` in my `~/Ubuntu One` folder and in `~/Documents` (which is synchronized too), 
but it seems that it also doesn't work.

Of course I'm the owner of `var/www` and I (and my group) have all rights (*771*).

Comment: It seems U1 doesn't support symlinks at the moment: https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/does-ubuntu-one-support-symlinks-or-hard-links/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use rsync so synx those folders regularly
The information **will be** duplicated but at least is a bit easier than copy pasting.

```
rsync /var/www /home/your_user/desired_folder
```

you can even make an automated script to run at certain time or just to be fired up with a quicker command

Comment: OK, thank you :) P.s. It's should be `rsync -l -r /var/www /home/user/destination`

Answer (score 2):

I also find different solution. We can use `deja-backup` program to synchronise backup which contains inter alia `var/www` folder ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the opposite and put a symlink to ~/Ubuntu One/www in /var and activate the `FollowSymLinks` option in your server configuration for the /var directory. This should work.

Comment: I'm not sure I can do this, because I have crypted home folder. However it's very good idea in other case :]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use bind mounting to [bind mount](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount) the folder under a folder which is synced with Ubuntu One.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of solving the issue without having to duplicate files would be to simply change the location of the public files in Apache from var/www to a location in your home folder.

Simply look in: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and change the DocumentRoot to a location in your documents folder, copy the contents of var/www into the new folder you created and set Ubuntu one to back up.